# Differences between /* */ and // in javascript

Tags: javascript, comments

I have searched everywhere for the answer to this, but I can't seem to find it. Maybe i'm looking in the wrong place?
Anyway, I'm trying to figure out all the differences between `/* */`, and `//` comments. I know that `//` is line end, and that `/* */` can be used n multiple lines, and start or end on the same line, but is one preffered over the other? Is one faster? And also, what are the differences between `/** /*` and `/* */`?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A comment is a comment.

Comment: `//` is a single-line comment and `/**/` are multi-line comments. `/** */` is used for PHPDoc to make automatic documentations, but is a simple comment.

Comment: The first one gives me a sense of a smiley or a Star Trek character, but the second one doesn't.

Comment: Google's "I'm lucky", using your tags (`javascript`, `comments`) - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comments.asp

Comment: @LcSalazar a url pointing towards w3schools proves that you're not lucky :p

Comment: @AmitJoki - Totally agree...

Comment: [MDN Comments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both comments work almost the same.

There is only one difference.

`//` is a single-line comment.

Example:

```
//This is a comment
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
//This is another one
```

`/* */` and `/** */` are multi-line comments.

Example:

```
/*A new example
 var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
Still inside the comment*/
```

The syntax `/** */` is used for [PHPDocumentator](http://www.phpdoc.org/) to make automatic documentations.

Regarding the speed:
NONE! There is no speed penality!
Probably on old IE versions (those don't like messy code and slow down A LOT).

About usability:

Do not use multi-line comments to comment a single line. Otherwise, there wouldn't be a need for single-line comments.
Same goes for the oposite.

For a simple example and a good read, you can check the [W3Schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comments.asp) about this (as stated [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412609/differences-between-and-in-javascript/28412991#comment45158771_28412609)).

---

Outside the scope of this answer, you can use comments to quickly hide parts you want to test.

Consider the following code:

```
/*// var str='This is in a comment'; //*
alert('This is still a comment'); /**/
```

By changing the first comment, from `/*/*/` to `//*/`, you will have the following code:

```
//*/ var str='This is in a comment'; //*
alert('This is still a comment'); /**/
```

And changing the first to `/*/*/`, you obtain this:

```
/*/*/ var str='This is in a comment'; //*
alert('This is still a comment'); /**/
```

Now, changing the comment `//*` to `/*`, you obtain this code:

```
/*/*/ var str='This is in a comment'; /*
alert('This is still a comment'); /**/
```

This is very useful sometimes to debug some problems and to quickly comment huge blocks of code in a very easy way.